# CORS AJAX Call not Successful

Tags: javascript, ajax, cors

I have an AJAX call trying to execute the following CORS request to a Web Server (I am currently testing using only the latest version of Chrome):

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("get", "http://www.web_server_url.com/query", true);
xhr.onload = function(){
};
xhr.send(null);
```

Meanwhile, I am still getting the following message:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.web_server_url.com/query. Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Would someone know what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is exactly what it says in the error: The server at `www.web_server_url.com` is not allowing the `localhost` origin. It's up to the server to decide whether to allow the origin of the call. In this case, apparently it's not allowing it.

The way [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) works, the server replies to the request (or a "preflight" request) with headers either allowing or disallowing the origin on the basis of the information the browser sends it.

Comment: Thank you T.J. Since my request is a get one, using any preflighted parameters wouldn’t change anything, right? The server is the Google Trends one. One would have thought that their server should be opened, no?

Comment: Or perhaps because the origin is localhost?

Comment: @JF0001: You'll have to look at the Google Trends documentation to see what requests they allow via CORS. It could be that they disallow `localhost` but allow other hosts, or it could be that they don't support CORS at all (and, for example, expect you to use JSON-P instead).

Comment: Actually T.J., I thought that the message “is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin” originated from the browser, and not the server, no?

Comment: @JF0001: In general, the browser gives you that message *because* the server at the other end disallowed the request. So the *message* may be from the browser, but it's because of the information the target srever gave it. The browser can't decide whether to allow a cross-origin call on its own (except browsers that disallow all calls from `file:` protocols and such), it has to ask the target server.

Comment: Thank you again T.J. The data returned by the server is in the following format: document.write('<iframe src="//www.google.com/trends/my_query_words"></iframe>'); Would you have any idea on how to handle this type of results?

Comment: @JF0001: That looks like it's expecting to be retrieved via a `script` tag, not via XHR.

Comment: Actually, I am using a Script Tag for the initial upload of the iframe, which works perfectly. Meanwhile, when I try to use a new script tag in a div with different query parameters in the url (after user input), I am obtaining the same error message (Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin), explaining why I was trying to use CORS.